# How to get content of a repository through GitHub API v4?

Tags: github, graphql, github-api

I'm trying to migrate my project from GitHub API v3 to v4.
How to get the files or directories of a repository through GraphQL API just like what I've done with the following RESTful API in v3:
`GET /repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:path` ?

I've read the document of GitHub API v4 but failed to find anything about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For searching the directory:

```
query {
  repository(name: "<repo>", owner: "<owner>") {
    object(expression: "master:") {
      ... on Tree {
        entries {
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And for getting the file content:

```
query { 
  repository(name: "<repo>", owner: "<owner>") {
    object(expression: "master:<path>") {
      ... on Blob {
        oid
        byteSize
        text
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Reference: https://github.community/t5/GitHub-API-Development-and/GraphQL-getting-filename-file-content-and-commit-date/td-p/17861